# Concurrent connections and Prefork MPM module in Ubuntu

Tags: apache2

I'm testing my server to know how many concurrent connections it support. I configure my mpm_prefork.conf this way:

```
# prefork MPM
# StartServers: number of server processes to start
# MinSpareServers: minimum number of server processes which are kept spare
# MaxSpareServers: maximum number of server processes which are kept spare
# MaxRequestWorkers: maximum number of server processes allowed to start
# MaxConnectionsPerChild: maximum number of requests a server process serves

<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers             5
    MinSpareServers       5
    MaxSpareServers      10
    MaxRequestWorkers     100000
    MaxConnectionsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

But when my server receives ~8200 concurrent connections, an error is fired and apache not respond anymore:

```
[notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

The server have enough memory and left over

The configurations is ok? I have to change anything?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your apache configuration looks alright.

With so many connection you can get problems with system ressources:

- What are the ulimts for the runtime user of your apache `cat
  /etc/security/limits.conf`
- if you have concurrent connections your system could be depleted of ports; check `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range`

Monitor your system activity online while your test is running; open a console on your server and start `vmstat 2` before you test and observe the values.

Also you could set your a higher log level in the main httpd.conf `LogLevel info`. Maybe you get some hints before your webserver stuffs it; otherwise try with debug (do not forget to switch back to warn or errror afterwards ;-) )